# mysql - count the total matches for each row in a distant table

Tags: mysql

If I have two tables

[image]

and

[image]

I want a result that looks like this:

[image]

```
SELECT app_status.title, count(*) as count FROM application as app LEFT JOIN application_status as app_status ON app.application_status_id  = app_status.application_status_id GROUP BY app.application_status_id;
```

I have tried the above query but it only returns values if they exist. which means it will count > 0 but if its = 0 then it wont include that row and ends up looking like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have the `left join` in the wrong order.  In addition:

- Change the `count()` to count from the second table.
- Change the `group by` to match the first `select` column.
- The aggregation column should be from the first table in the `left join`.

So, the resulting query is:

```
SELECT app_status.title, count(app.application_status_id) as count
FROM application_status app_status LEFT JOIN
     application app 
     ON app.application_status_id = app_status.application_status_id
GROUP BY app_status.title
ORDER BY MIN(app_status.application_status_id);
```

Comment: worked straight away. my aggregate knowledge is a bit off. thanks for your time and prompt answer.